# Time measurement not working in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, c++11, search, time

I'm trying to make run time measurements of simple algorithms like linear sort. The problem is that no matter what I do, the time measurement won't work as intended. I get the same search time no matter what problem size I use. Both me and other people who've tried to help me are equally confused.

I have a linear sort function that looks like this:

```
// Search the N first elements of 'data'.
int linearSearch(vector<int> &data, int number, const int N) {
    if (N < 1 || N > data.size()) return 0;

    for (int i=0;i<N;i++) {
        if (data[i] == number) return 1;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I've tried to take time measurement with both time_t and chrono from C++11 without any luck, except more decimals. This is how it looks like right now when i'm searching.

```
vector<int> listOfNumbers = large list of numbers;

for (int i = 15000; i <= 5000000; i += 50000) {
    const clock_t start = clock();

    for (int a=0; a<NUMBERS_TO_SEARCH; a++) {
        int randNum = rand() % INT_MAX;
        linearSearch(listOfNumbers, randNum, i);
    }

    cout << float(clock() - start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC << endl;
}
```

**The result?**
0.126, 0.125, 0.125, 0.124, 0.124, ... (same values?)

I have tried the code with both VC++, g++ and on different computers.

First I thought it was my implementation of the search algorithms that was at fault. But a linear sort like the one above can't become any simpler, it's clearly O(N). How can the time be the same even when the problem size is increased by so much? I'm at loss what to do.

**Edit 1:**
Someone else might have an explanation why this is the case. But it actually worked in release mode after changing:
    if (data[i] == number)

To:

```
if (data.at(i) == number)
```

I have no idea why this is the case, but linear search could be time measured correctly after that change.

Comment: Does `data` have enough elements?

Comment: Doesn't the data to search appear early in the vector?

Comment: The vector have about 5.7 million elements. Right now data is prime numbers in sorted order. But i've also tried to initialize it with random data with the same result.

Comment: What if all of the elements of the vector is `1` and search target (`randNum`) is all `2`?

Comment: After changing data to 1s only and searching for 2s only, I get the same time, somewhere between 0.124 and 0.127.

Comment: if you want more precision on the time measurement, try `std::chrono::steady_clock::time_point t0` and then `std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::duration<double> >(std::chrono::steady_clock::now() - t0_)).count()`

Comment: Beware that `rand()` returns a random number up to `RAND_MAX`.

Comment: Did you try to debug to see what's actually going on in that linear search function?

Comment: Didn't find anything in particular, except that int should've been size_t. But even so, the only observation I can make is that running the program in debug mode gives actual resonable values, while running it in release-mode gives the same values no matter what I do.

Answer (score 3):

The reason for the about-constant execution times is that the compiler is able to optimize away parts of the code.

Specifically looking at this part of the code:

```
  for (int a=0; a<NUMBERS_TO_SEARCH; a++) {
      int randNum = rand() % INT_MAX;
      linearSearch(listOfNumbers, randNum, i);
  }
```

When compiling with g++5.2 and optimization level `-O3`, the compiler can optimize away the call to `linearSearch()` completely. This is because the result of the code is the same with or without that function being called.
The return value of `linearSearch` is not used anywhere, and the function does not seem to have side-effects. So the compiler can remove it.

You can cross-check and modify the inner loop as follows. The execution times shouldn't change:

```
  for (int a=0; a<NUMBERS_TO_SEARCH; a++) {
      int randNum = rand() % INT_MAX;
      // linearSearch(listOfNumbers, randNum, i);
  }
```

What remains in the loop is the call to `rand()`, and this is what you seem to be measuring. When changing the `data[i] == number` to `data.at(i) == number`, the call to `linearSearch` is not side-effects-free as `at(i)` may throw an out-of-range exception. So the compiler does not completely optimize the `linearSearch` code away. However, with g++5.2, it will still inline it and not make a function call.

Answer (score 0):

clock() is measuring CPU time, maybe you want time(NULL)? check this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12223842/measuring-time-in-c?rq=1)

Comment: Tried it, but it gives me the same values still. No matter how many iterations I do, they give about the same time.

Answer (score 0):

The `start` should be before the `for` loop. In your case the `start` is different for each iteration, it is constant between the `{ ... }`.

`const clock_t start = clock();
 for (int i = 15000; i <= 5000000; i += 50000){
   ...
 }`

Comment: That's because I take time measurement of many different sizes. First I do for N = 15000 then N = 65000, etc up until N = 5000000. The loop inside is how many numbers I search for for each N.